# Basecamp OAuth flow not accepting redirect_uri query parameters

Tags: redirect, oauth, basecamp

It seems like the OAuth2 `redirect_uri` for Basecamp does not accept optional parameters (e.g. `mydomain.com/callback?user_id=1`). In fact, it only matches on the *exact* `redirect_uri` that I've provided when registering my app. Because of this, I am unable to identify the authenticated user when receiving the redirect.

Is this intended? If so, how can I uniquely identify my user on redirect?

One possibly solution is to use the `state` parameter as a identifier - however, this doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: its intended. Maybe fetching email etc about users from oauth provider would help you?

Answer (score 1):

you can base64 encode your query string, then pass that as state.   The state then comes back to you, you can decode it, use the code, set your session then redirect to where you were before, or where you want to be.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the least messy solution at the moment.

Comment: The basic Idea is, I was somewhere.   I needed to go to google to authenticate, or do some other action, google passes me back to a predefined url for the purpose of handling your the [code] from google.   That is the purpose of that URL, when it's done, it can redirect you to where you should be, now that you have what you need.   You could also just set your $_GET at that point and continue on without a redirect.